# How Do I display information from the joins table with the new Rails 3 query interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I have two models Horse and Race.

```
class Horse < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :races
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :horse
end
```

Now I want to use the new rails 3 query interface to see the Horse name and all its races.

```
Horse.joins(:races)  # I get an active record relation that only displays horse data

Horse.joins(:races).count #Yields 31 the exact number of races.

Horse.joins(:races).all #Yields an Array of 31 Horse, but no race data

Horse.joins(:races).all.select("horses.*, starters.*") #Yields active record relation with only Horse data.
```

**Question 1**: What's the correct query to yield complete horse and race records.

**Question 2:** What's the correct query to yield the horse name and all of the race record.

I know this is very basic, but I'm stumped. I sense I'd doing something wrong with the relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see I don't thing you're doing anything wrong with your relations.

If you want to see all horses with each of their races:

```
Horse.includes(:races).each do |horse|
  puts horse.name
  horse.races.each do |race|
    puts race.name
  end
end
```

Assuming I understand your question, your use of `joins(:races)` is irrelevant here. First, it will not automatically pull any data from the races table. It will simply add an inner join between horses and races. If horse N has 10 races, that query will then return 10 instances of horses N, which is probably not useful in this instance.

The `includes(:races)` above isn't strictly necessary - it just loads all the races at once with one query, as opposed to *n* queries (*n* being the number of horses). Just saves time and resources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So a block and puts are required.  I thought I could achieve this in the IRB with a one (two) liner. For example, Horse.includes(races).select("horses.*, races.*").  Perhaps not. Thanks again.

Comment: Well a block and puts aren't necessarily required - it's just the way I happened to type it. It's certainly achievable with a one-liner. `stuff = Horse.each { |h| "#{h.name}: #{h.races.map(&:name).join(', ')}" }` would also work.